# How to get images of contacts using ContactPicker?

Tags: c#, windows-8

Developing for windows 8 and want to use contact's pictures in it from the People App. But How would you do that in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the contact information api using the [`GetThumbNailAsync` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactinformation.getthumbnailasync.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).